# TeeChart - Rotating Multiline Annotation (Text) Tool gives wrong result

Tags: c#, .net, charts, teechart

Currently I am working on one requirement, wherein I want rotate TeeChart's Annotation Tool (.Net Version) which is having Multiline Text. I successfully updated code to rotate single line Annotation Tool. The code snippet of which can be found below.

```
string[] s = tmp.Split(Texts.LineSeparator);

        int tmpCenterX, tmpCenterY;
        Point tmpP = new Point(0, 0);
        Rectangle r = shape.ShapeBounds;
        if (Angle != 0)
        {
            Graphics3D.RectCenter(r, out tmpCenterX, out tmpCenterY);

            double tmp1 = Angle * Utils.PiStep;
            int tmpNumRow = 1;
            int tmpRowHeight = tmpHeight;
            double S = Math.Sin(tmp1);
            double C = Math.Cos(tmp1);

            int tmpY = tmpNumRow * tmpRowHeight - (r.Bottom - tmpCenterY);
            tmpP.X = Utils.Round(tmpCenterX - Utils.Round(tmpY * S));
            tmpP.Y = Utils.Round(tmpCenterY - Utils.Round(tmpY * C));

            tmpP.X = tmpCenterX;
            tmpP.Y = r.Top + tmpNumRow * tmpRowHeight;

            if (shape.Visible)
            {
                shape.DrawRectRotated(g, r, Utils.Round(Angle % 360), 0);
            }
        }

        for (int t = 1; t <= tmpN; t++)
        {

            if (TextAlign == StringAlignment.Center && tmpN > 1)
            {
                float auxW = g.Chart.Graphics3D.TextWidth(s[t - 1]);
                x = Utils.Round((shape.ShapeBounds.Left + shape.ShapeBounds.Right) / 2) - Utils.Round(auxW / 2);
            }


            if (Angle != 0)
            {
                Point rotatedPoint = RotatedPoint(r, (int)Angle);
                g.RotateLabel(rotatedPoint.X  , rotatedPoint.Y + tmpHeight * (t - 1), 0, s[t - 1], (float)Angle);
            }
            else
            {
                CalcTextXY(ref x, ref y);
                DrawString(g, x, y, t, tmpHeight, s);
            }
        }
```

But for multiline text this code is not working. Please check the following screenshot for error I am getting.
[Error in Multiline Rotated Text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YI4o3.png)

Any help on this will be of great help. Thanking you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

`RotateLabel` does it correctly for me here:

[image]

```
private void TChart1_AfterDraw(object sender, Steema.TeeChart.Drawing.Graphics3D g)
{
  String tmp = "Multiline\nText\nAngle 45 Degree";

  g.RotateLabel(100, 150, tmp, 45);
}
```